# App-wide error handling for ASP.NET MVC2 web app?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

I want to implement an app-wide error handling mechanism for an ASP.NET MVC2 web app.  What is the standard way to do this?

I want to make sure that the user never sees a 404 error, a 500 error, or a core dump.

Comment: Elmah is a very popular library for exception handling: [ELMAH in asp.net mvc2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301163/elmah-in-asp-net-mvc2) More similar questions: [Error handling for ASP.NET MVC 2 and IIS 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545906/error-handling-for-asp-net-mvc-2-and-iis-7-0) [Proper error handling in ASP.NET MVC2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711604/proper-error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc2)